# Sliding box on mouse over - CSS

Tags: css, animation, hover, slide, box

I'ld like to know if there is a better way to do this:

Also I don't think it will work smoothly in a responsive page so do you have any ideas to make it work without certain positionings like 'bottom:-45px;'.

I just wondered about this so this is not something that I'm going to use somewhere.
I know it could be done with jquery easily but I wonder if there is a chance to achieve this effect with pure CSS

```css
.d1 {
  width: 320px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;position: relative;
}

.d2 {
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  border: none;
}

.d3 {
  width: 90%;position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: none;
}

.d3 p, .d2 p, d1 p {
  z-index:999;
  position:relative;

}




.hov {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background-color: #300;
  position:relative;
  opacity:0;
  bottom:-45px;left:0px;
  z-index:0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 1.285, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.d2 { pointer-events: none;}
.d3 { pointer-events: auto;}

.d2:hover .hov{
opacity:1;
 bottom:-123px;
}

.d1:hover .hov{
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
div1
  <div class="d2">
    <div class="hov" id="hov">
    </div>
    <p>
      div2
    </p>
    <div class="d3">
      <p>
      div3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is: box should appear when mouse over and should slide between div2 and div3. div1 just the main container.

Comment: I don't understand, box does slide between div2 and div3, do you want it to move more smoothly?

Comment: No. What I asked is can we do the same thing with simplier css and without determining the position of the box as px. I feel like its not the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think I managed to do it. In this case there are two elements so I placed them to top and bottom of the main container.

```css
.d1 {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}

.d2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.d3 {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.d3 p,
.d2 p {
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
}

.hov {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #300;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 1.285, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.d3:hover+.hov {
  top: 60%;
}

.d1:hover .hov {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">

  <div class="d2">
    <p> div2 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="d3">
    <p> div3 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="hov"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, what you would call a 'certain positioning' would be required, but if you were to run it with a responsive page, the user, with a mobile phone, would have to click the area, before it moves, instead of hovering it. Using pure CSS would be a drag, because you have to literally loop over the codes all around.

My advice is, it's generally okay to use a specific number (i.e. -45px) as long as it's only for vertical measurements.

Comment: Hey thanks! You're right that shouldn't be a problem to use specific vertical measurements. Eventually everything already sized as specific numbers. I think smoothest way is using jquery and dragging the box to position of the hover element.